# Remove .php extension with .htaccess when working live on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have issue in displaying my pages without the file extension using .htaccess

1. I have created a .htaccess file(using notepad) in my server root folder and save it as .htaccess.
2. Following is the code which I have written in my .htaccess file.

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
   ```
3. I have also tried with following code too.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
   ```
4. After then I have saved my file and uploaded(to the project root) to server using FTP as filezilla.
5. I have run my url as

   ```
   10.130.1.30/nexus-dashboard
   ```
6. Then my login page appears and after login it shows in the url as

   ```
   10.130.1.30/nexus-dashboard/users.php
   ```

So after uploading .htaccess and writing code in it, still shows the .php extension.

This is what I don't want. And it should show like

```
10.130.1.30/nexus-dashboard/users
```

I have checked in many sites and they suggested me like after all above steps plz change all your anchor tags page redirects to normal page name.

ex: `<a href="users.php>users</a> to <a href="users">users</a>`

after the above steps it displayed the error as page not found.

**So, Please its a request to you all to help me regarding my issue. I shall be very much grateful to you.**

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your htaccess, did you check the file permission ,is it 644?

Comment: @Starkeen - Yes i have checked. But still the same problem persists :(

Comment: "change all your anchor tags" - this is actually the very first thing you should do, otherwise _every_ time the user clicks a link they will be redirected! Is mod_rewrite enabled on your server? Is `AllowOverride` set appropriately in your server config to allow mod_rewrite?

Comment: yes everything is enabled. only the left out part is to change all the anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `+MultiViews` instead of `-MultiViews`.
Multiviews turn on content negotiation, which essentially allows you to call 'foo.php' by requesting 'foo'.

See the 'Multiviews' paragraph in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#negotiation for more information.